# Mount a child component once in a lifecycle of React app and use the same instance whenever needed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have scenario where the grand child or great-grant child component needs to be mounted only once . And once it gets mounted , the same component can be reused whenever needed instead of mounting it again and again.
how to achieve this in REACT ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you actually can't do that in React.

The idea is that whenever a component is not "needed" (meaning it's not being currently viewed, a case you just cannot modify, it's one of the React fundamentals), it is being unmounted (to improve performance). So, in consequence, when you enter it again, React renders (mounts) it again, from scratch.

The only solution I can think of is disabling the component from being unmounted, which means disabling the components' change; and this is most certainly not something you asked for...

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Disabling components being unmounted also helps me. Kindly let me know how to do that.

Comment: I meant: literally disablibg the component change, like disabling all the relevant buttons and/or making the Router point to just this one component. It basically comes down to having to constantly STAY on this one component. These all are rather awful solutions, as React doesn't support "disabling unmounting" - it's against it's core idea.